# Orthogonal basis of a quadratic module

Tags: orthogonality, quadratic-forms

I'm studying quadratic forms and I have to prove that every quadratic module $(V,Q)$ has an orthogonal basis, where $V$ is a vectorial space on $\mathbb{K}$ and $Q$ a quadratic form on $V$. I'm following Serre's proof in "A course in Arithmetic".

Assuming that $dim(V) \ge 1$, let $x$ be a non isotropic element of $V$ and let $H$ be the orthogonal complement of the subspace $\mathbb{K}x$. Then $Q$ is non degenerate on $\mathbb{K}x$ so $x \notin H$ and $\mathbb{K}x \cap H = \{0\}$. I need to say that $V=\mathbb{K}x \oplus H$, and I know this is true when $Q$ is nondegenerate on $V$ and on $\mathbb{K}x$, but in this case I don't assume that $V$ is non degenerate. So how can I say that $dim(V)=1+dim(H)$?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You are missing some crucial information here. For example, is $Q$ regular? What characteristic does $K$ have? In general, for all fields and all quadratic forms, the claim that there always exists an orthogonal basis is wrong.

Comment: $\mathbb{K}$ is a field oh characteristic not $2$ and $V$ is a finite-dimensional vectorial space over $\mathbb{K}$. I don't know what regular means. I only miss the reason why, if $Q$ is nondegenerate over $V$ and $x$ is non isotropic, it's true that $V=\mathbb{K}x \oplus H$

Answer (score 1):

you can first suppose that $Q$ is degenerate. Then you can write $V=V^0 \hat{\oplus} U$ where $U$ is a supplementary subspace of $V^0$. By induction you know that $U$ have an orthogonal basis and $V^0$ also (by definition). The union of both is an orthogonal basis of $V$.

Then you can prove the case with $Q$ nondegenerate :) .